# Jquery Submit selected form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a page which has multiple forms. Each form is set as :

```
<form method='post' name='test'>
<form method='post' name='new'>
<form method='post' name='add'>
<form method='post' name='rem'>
```

Each form has a submit button:

```
<input id="test" type="submit" value="test" />
```

The **value** and **id** changes depending on which form you are in.

I'm using Jquery to submit one form.

```
$('#test').on("click",function() {
    if (confirm ('Continue?')) {
        $(this).submit();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

But wondered if there was any way to amend this so it could submit any of the forms ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click handler for each button, use a form submit handler

```
$('form').on("submit", function () {
    return confirm('Continue?');
});
```

---

If you want to maintain the same format then, you can target all the submit submit buttons inside the forms

```
$('form input:submit').on("click", function () {
    if (confirm('Continue?')) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use multiple forms in this way

```
<form method='post' name='test' id="form1">
<input id="test" type="button" onclick="submitForm(1)" value="test" />
<form method='post' name='test' id="form2">
<input id="test" type="button" onclick="submitForm(2)" value="test" />
```

For submit form using jquery or Ajax you can use below code

```
function submitForm(counterVal){$.post('form-post-url/',$('#form'+counterVal).serialize(),function(resp)
    {
        /// here is your response
    });
```

This way you can use easily nth level form.